# Add days Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME, ADD_DAYS (ORDER_DATE, 20)
FROM CUSTOMER, ORDERS;
```

Oracle Express says ADD_DAYS invalid? Any ideas what Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please always include the actual error message provided.

Comment: `Select sysdate, sysdate+1 from dual;`  Add_Days isn't an oracle function. https://community.oracle.com/thread/58184?tstart=0

Answer (score 77):

If you want to add N days to your days. You can use the plus operator as follows -

```
SELECT ( SYSDATE + N ) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 48):

You can use the plus operator to add days to a date.

```
order_date + 20
```

Answer (score 44):

In a more general way you can use "INTERVAL". Here some examples:

1) add a day

```
select sysdate + INTERVAL '1' DAY from dual;
```

2) add 20 days

```
select sysdate + INTERVAL '20' DAY from dual;
```

2) add some minutes

```
select sysdate + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE from dual;
```

Comment: Just a note: do NOT use this to add months! For an example why, try `select to_date('31.03.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy') + interval '1' month from dual`.

Comment: @vadipp right. We should use `ADD_MONTHS(date, 1)`. Here it would return `30-APR-19`

Answer (score 14):

Some disadvantage of "INTERVAL '1' DAY" is that bind variables cannot be used for the number of days added. Instead, numtodsinterval can be used, like in this small example:

```
select trunc(sysdate) + numtodsinterval(:x, 'day') tag
from dual
```

See also: [NUMTODSINTERVAL in Oracle Database Online Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm)

Comment: you saved us today : )

Answer (score 12):

It's Simple.You can use

```
select (sysdate+2) as new_date from dual;
```

This will add two days from current date.

Answer (score 2):

One thing about
`select (sysdate+3) from dual`
is that the sysdate is interpreted as date.

But if you want to use a custom date, not local, you need to make sure it is interpreted as date, not string. Like so (adding 3 days):

```
select (to_date('01/01/2020')+3) from dual
```