# Oracle to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am trying to extract data from Oracle source to SQL Server table using SSIS 2008.

When I tried to run a oracle source using 
a source query with `LAST_UPD >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE-7)'` I get 16Mrows, but in the oracle query source it only selects 150K rows.

Now, I would like to use the below clause, but I am not sure if I would get my expected row count using SSIS.

```
1) SELECT * FROM Tbl1 WHERE LAST_UPD >= TRUNC(SYSDATE -7)
```

What would be best to use? Is there anything wrong with date convertion in SSIS (oracle to SQL)?

Any suggestions?

Comment: forgot to tag SSIS means downvote. :(

Comment: No, adding it probably means that. Your query has nothing to do with SSIS or SQL Server. You are simply asking how to perform date calculations in Oracle. I'm sure there are a lot of duplicates that show how to do this. Converting anything to date, using arbitrary formats no less, is guaranteed to cause *more* problems

Comment: You also forgot to explain what the actual problem is. If `SYSDATE - 7` doesn't work, find the correct syntax. Use INTERVAL or ADD_DAYS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add days Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451226/add-days-oracle-sql)