# How can I add a value to a day SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I add a value to a day?

| Field | Value |
| --- | --- |
| data_nascita | 12-31-2021 |
|  |  |

example: day=12  value=40  tot=12+40=52

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451226/add-days-oracle-sql)

Comment: Is there a function that allows me to add a certain day of a date with a value?

Comment: I would need to extract the day from the date field that contains day-month-year and add the day to a value

Comment: Are you sure that your value is `DD-MM-YYYY`? There is not a 31st month in the year.

Comment: Btw, the **day** seems like the **month**, since **31** cannot be a value for month...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `EXTRACT` function:

```sql
SELECT field,
       value,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM value) + 40 AS new_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Field, Value) AS
SELECT 'data_nascita', DATE '2021-12-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FIELD | VALUE | NEW_VALUE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | data_nascita | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | 71 |

If you want to get `12 + 40 = 51` then use `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM value)`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bf8acb813692874f565b858d2ffe1a2f)*