# MSACCESS SQL Date greater than 3 days ago - Pass Through query to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, oracle-sqldeveloper, ms-access-2016

I am having an issue trying to add a portion to my WHERE clause to get only the last 3 days of data rather than grab the whole table. The date format comes through as 'dd-Mon-yy'

Here is my current WHERE clause

```
WHERE ("IAINVN00"."REF_LOCN" LIKE '51C%' 
        OR "IAINVN00"."REF_LOCN" LIKE '511%')
```

This works fine, just brings back way too much data. When I add:

```
and "IAINVN00"."ADJDATE" >= (Date()-3)
```

This brings back an error of "ODBC--call failed. [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00936: missing expression (#936)"

I have tried using this as well and get the same error

```
DateAdd("d",-3,Date())
```

Comment: Does this help: [Add days Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451226/add-days-oracle-sql)

Comment: Oracle or MS Access? Please only tag the relevant RDBMS, and only tag desktop tools if the issue is related to that tool.

Comment: Maciej, this was the fix. I don't know why I didn't think to use sysdate to begin with. I figured MSACCESS would not like that terminology. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, instead of using Date, I needed to use SysDate.

```
and "IAINVN00"."ADJDATE" >= sysdate - 3
```